# Sequence approaching 1 , proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove

$$1 + {\pi\over \sqrt{n}}\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}1$$

Proof: Let $\epsilon > 0$. We need to find a positive integer $N$, such that $n \ge N$.

Now

$$\left|  1 + {\pi\over\sqrt{n}} - 1 \right| < \epsilon$$

Then, ${\pi\over\sqrt{n}} < \epsilon$ .

Squaring ${\pi\over\sqrt n} <\epsilon$, we have  ${\pi^2\over n} < \epsilon^2$. So, $n > {\pi^2\over \epsilon^2}$.

Now $n \ge N \implies  {1\over n}\le  {1\over N} <$

Please can someone help me? I would really appreciate the feedback.
Thank you.

Comment: Right, so $n > N = \frac{\epsilon^2}{\pi^2}$. What is the problem?

Comment: Could it be n > N  = π^2/ ε^(2)? Since n >= N.

Comment: Choose $N=\left[{\pi^2\over\epsilon^2}\right]+1$ and you're golden.

Comment: How about $n > \left \lceil \frac{\pi^2}{\epsilon^2} \right \rceil$

Answer (score 0):

$$\text{ For any $\epsilon > 0$ choose a positive integer } N \text{ so that we have }N>\frac{\pi^2}{\epsilon^2}  $$
$$\text{ Then we have } n\geq N> \frac{\pi^2}{\epsilon^2}\implies n> \frac{\pi^2}{\epsilon^2}$$
$$\text{ Taking the reciprocal of both sides of the inequality gives }\frac{1}{n}< \frac{\epsilon^2}{\pi^2}$$
$$\text{ Thus }\frac{\pi^2}{n}< \epsilon ^2 \implies \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{n}}< \epsilon$$